# c# how to convert IntPtr to struct?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

A simple ATL com server:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyMath::get_Version(sVersionStruct **ppVer)
{
    sVersionStruct* pVer = reinterpret_cast<sVersionStruct*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(sVersionStruct)));
    if (!pVer) {
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    } else {
        *pVer = ver_;
        *ppVer = pVer;
        return S_OK;
    }
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CMyMath::put_Version(sVersionStruct* ver)
{
    ver_ = *ver;
    return S_OK;
}
```

idl definition:

```
typedef 
[
    uuid(72A4AA5B-6AD0-4249-B4CB-2FFB08301608)
]
struct tagVersionStruct {
    int majorVersion;
    int minorVersion;
} sVersionStruct;

    [propget]
    HRESULT Version([out, retval, ref]sVersionStruct** ver);
    [propput]
    HRESULT Version([in]sVersionStruct* ver)
```

c# .net client:

```
    MathServLib.sVersionStruct ver;
    ver.minorVersion = 1;
    ver.majorVersion = 3;
    math.set_Version(ver);

    ver.minorVersion = 0;
    ver.majorVersion = 0;
    IntPtr ptr = math.get_Version();
    int i = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr); // RETURN RIGHT VALUE 3
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, ver);
```

The last line returns the Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. This structure is not value type.
```

Since `Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr)` could return the right value `3`, why cannot convert IntPtr to struct?

PS: The sVersionStruct from ILSpy:

```
namespace MathServLib
{
    [Guid("72A4AA5B-6AD0-4249-B4CB-2FFB08301608")]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct sVersionStruct
    {
        public int majorVersion;
        public int minorVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: @SLaks: System.ArgumentException, this struct is not value type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should call the overload of PtrToStructure that expects a type instead of an object. That's what's causing the error probably:

```
var ver = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(MathServLib.sVersionStruct));
```

Comment: There is an overload which takes object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/30ex8z62(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I read the msdn which said the first overload does not accept value type.

Comment: @Hamlet-Hakobyan: for value types (structs), you need the overload with the Type parameter.

Comment: This answer will return an object, you'll need to do a casting. But you can avoid the casting with generics: var ver = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MathServLib.sVersionStruct>(ptr);