# setting mouse hooks in C# with setwindowshookex: wparam and lparam always return constant

Tags: c#, .net, hook

I'm working to implement mouse hooks in C# using setwindowshookex

I have code that detects when mouse events are triggered and hands the data to the assigned callback which, based on lots of sample code I've seen other places, should conform to a mouseProc callback function which takes an int as the "ncode" (which I cannot figure out what it is.), the wParam and the lParam.

Which, based on what I've seen, provides the type of event via wParam and additional information via lParam.

The type of event is denoted via an enumeration that is detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468877(v=vs.85).aspx) in the documentation.

However the documentation associated with these enumerations suggests that they are returned from the [WindowProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) callback where wParam and lParam are associated with modifier keys and xy coordinates of the mouse respectively.

I cannot find documentation that details the callback I am currently using so I'm not sure if I'm just not looking in the right place or if perhaps .NET has been updated.

Regardless of 3 or 4 parameters on the callback, the values for wParam and lParam are always constant. wParam appears to correspond with the enum discussed previously (e.g. for left click down, I receive hex 0x0201). However, lParam is some constant number that I cannot relate to anything. It does not appear to be an address pointing to meaningful data.

This is a short working sample of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MouseMonitor
{
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(Utils.HookType idHook, MouseProc lpfn, int hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    public delegate int MouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private int hookID = 0;
    private MouseProc hookCallback = null;

    public MouseMonitor()
    {
        this.hookCallback = new MouseProc(HookCallback);

        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
             this.hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(Utils.HookType.WH_MOUSE_LL, this.hookCallback, Utils.GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private int HookCallback(int nCode,  IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
             // Do something.
        }
        return Utils.CallNextHookEx(this.hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

So I'm not sure if my understanding of the documentation is incorrect and I'm not using the proper callback or something else. I would at the very least expect a different value every time even if it's garbage or bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN your `lParam` is a pointer to [MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644968(v=vs.85).aspx) which can be easily converted from pointer to structure using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680557/c-sharp-how-to-convert-intptr-to-struct.).

Working code would look like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Point
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Point pt;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public uint wHitTestCode;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    private int HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            // Do something.
            var mhs = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine($"point: {mhs.pt.X} {mhs.pt.Y}");
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(this.hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: The documentation states you should test `nCode` before processing - if negative, just return value from `CallNextHookEx`, if 3 means it is a peek (and should probably be ignored?).